# Undefined property: ErrorController::$user in AppController.php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Versions

- CakePHP version: 3.7.5
- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
- Apache version: 2.4.25-3+deb9u6
- MariaDB version: 10.1.37
- PHP version: 7.0.33-0+deb9u3.

I am currently in the process of migrating our CakePHP site from 3.0.5 using php5 to 3.7.5 php7, most of our errors have been ironed out except one in particular.

I have attempted to find a solution for this, unfortunately unable find anything to point me in the right direction.

Error

> Undefined property: ErrorController::$user in /var/www/CMS/src/Controller/AppController.php on line 44 [CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 388]

AppController.php

```
39     public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
40         $this->user = $this->Auth->user();          
41     }
42
43     public function beforeRender(Event $event){
44         $this->set('logged_user',$this->user); //This line
45     }
```

Dump of $this->user

```
(
    [username] => ash
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [0] => Admin
        )

    [id] => 3
)
```

In the previous version we had no issues with this but has appeared in many places throughout the site after this upgrade. Unfortunately I do not have much experience with CakePHP.
:)

Comment: Can you var_dump $this->user?

Comment: @EvanGertis
(
    [username] => ash
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [0] => Admin
        )

    [id] => 3
)

Comment: I wish I could provide more help, but I will say it seems odd that you are trying to set this object to a string 'logged_user'. Are you sure you aren't suppose to be setting a specific property of the user object to 'logged_in'?

Comment: [**The default `ErrorController` implements `beforeFilter()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.7.1/src/Controller/ErrorController.php#L44), but doesn't invoke its parent method, ie `AppController::beforeFilter()`, where you populate the property, and I guess where you dynamically declare it, ie you haven't actually declared a concrete `user` property in your `AppController` class, hence the error.

Comment: try ```$this->set('logged_user', $this->Auth->user()); ```